# Play framework Handling websockets with actors in java

Tags: java, websocket, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am trying to implement websockets with actors in java. The place where we accept the websocket connection and create an ActorFlow.actorRef to handle websockets, is there any way to pass parameters to the websocket actor? I am following this example from documentation here .. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets#handling-websockets-with-actors

```
public WebSocket socket() { 
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(request -> 
        ActorFlow.actorRef(MyWebSocketActor::props, actorSystem, 
        materializer));
}
```

Is there any way to pass params to MyWebSocketActor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from implementing the Props function as suggested by @Igmar,

Someone from other forum suggested below and it works fine.

MyWebSocketActor::props is shorthand for (actorRef) -> MyWebSocketActor.props(actorRef)
so call it like (actorRef) -> MyWebSocketActor.props(actorRef, otherStuff)

Comment: This was a life saver migrating from Play 2.4 to 2.6.

Comment: This is indeed the one most important line I needed for our migration project. Note that the ActorFlow class which is normally used for bringing the things together is broken in Play 2.5 for Java. However, you can just take ActorFlow.actorRef() from Play 2.6 and copy that code whereever you want and use it. As our migration starts from Play 2.5 and its LegacyWebSockets, I needed this additional step.

Answer (score 0):

In general, passing arguments to an actor is the following :

```
final Props props = Props.create(SomeActorClass.class, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

You need to create props at the right place. The arguments are passed to the constructor of the actor class.

Comment: Ya i coded the Props.create like that but I was having trouble passing it from ActorFlow.actorRef. I tried calling it like "ActorFlow.actorRef(MyWebSocketActor::props(otherStuff), actorSystem, 
        materializer));)"
But it didn't work. A guy from other forum suggested that MyWebSocketActor::props is shorthand for (actorRef) -> MyWebSocketActor.props(actorRef)
so call it like (actorRef) -> MyWebSocketActor.props(actorRef, otherStuff)

This worked well.